# How to get rid of dandruff from hairs?

Tags: cleaning, personal-care, hair

In every winter my head skin become ruff and get dandruff which cause hair broken sometime when I shampoo my hairs it is clean just for hour or two after a day same thing happened again.

Can you please give me natural way to get rid of dandruff from my hairs?

Comment: Make sure your shampoo doesn't contain sulphates. This can be a main cause of dandruff for most people.

Answer (score 4):

I believe your main problem is your hair and scalp being too dry after cleaning. My skin and hair also remain very dry during winter. Here are some solutions-

One natural solution:

- Use avocado oil/argan oil to comb/brush through your hair, and maybe massage some on your scalp to keep everything nourished and moisturized.

Other solutions:

- Use conditioner after washing your hair. If you are not used to using conditioner before, it might take a few times to figure out how much to put on (or which brand to use) for best result.
- Use moisturizing shampoo/conditioner. You might or might not have significant improvement on your problem depending if it works well with your hair.
- Get some leave-in conditioner to put on after you get out of shower.
- There are moisturizing sprays available too if you feel that's more convenient than rubbing things onto your hair.

Like I said, if you don't already have a habit of putting stuff on your hair, it might take a few tries to figure out what works best for you. Hope this helps! :D

Answer (score 4):

Soak methi seeds (fenugreek seeds) overnight, make a fine paste of it and apply it to your scalp. Do it every week. It not only reduces dandruff but also makes your hair shiny and soft also reduces hair fall.

Answer (score 2):

I believe it is worth mentioning that washing your hair more often because of the dandruff can be counterproductive. Most shampoos are quite harsh detergents that also remove all the good stuff from your scalp that keeps the skin and hair healthy. If you wash your hair too often you dry out the skin and encourage it to get greasier more quickly because it is trying to counteract the stripping of oils by the shampoo.

One thing you could try is to reduce the frequency of washes. It takes some time for your scalp to adjust, but after a while it will produce less oil.

What I sometimes do, is I massage some oil (my favourite is coconut, but you can use olive/almond/etc. as well) into my scalp and onto the ends of my hair (they tend to get frizzy) some hours before I'm going to wash my hair or leave it in over night. An egg mask is also a low-budget, less harsh way to treat damaged hair ([this is just one exemplary recipe](http://mynaturalhairgrowth.net/egg-protein-hair-mask/)).

Generally speaking, I would not suggest to put *more* stuff onto your scalp and hair, as this might dry out your hair even more.

Comment: You can go so far as not using any shampoo. Just rinse a few times each week and comb or rinse your hair twice a day at least.

Answer (score 1):

One of the main causes of dandruff is [Malassezia globosa](https://youtu.be/TIe2oerd25c?t=258). Dandruff is an immune response to chemicals produced by this fungus.

So an effective way to treat dandruff is to kill this fungus. [The active ingredients in anti-dandruff shampoos target this fungus](https://youtu.be/TIe2oerd25c?t=395). You may only need to use the shampoo as little as once per week.

Answer (score 0):

Certain shampoos strip moisture from hair, and I don't see anyone pointing out that the shampoo may be part of the issue. Head and Shoulders is especially stripping of moisture, though there are many offenders.

I can recommend a few shampoo/conditioner sets that can help combat this dryness.

-Organix Moraccan Argon Oil (is a set)

-Really any Organix product (is a set)

-Three Minute Miracle Deep Conditioner by Aussie

-Loreal Everpure Conditioner

-Any shampoos or conditioners formulated for deep moisture or wavy/curly hair.

These can be purchased at any drugstore/pharmacy!

Using cold water can be less drying than hot water as well!

Hair Masks or Oils can be good to, but the true problem can probably be solved with any shampoo or conditioner listed above.

Answer (score 0):

One reason people get dandruff especially during winter is that they use hot water to wash their head. Stop using hot water if that's the case. Also, dry off immediately after shower.